# Modelling predictor as quadratic term lowers BIC but marginal effect plot shows linear distribution?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, effect-size, bic, marginal-effect

I am using a modified Hosmer Lemeshaw approach, culminating in all possible combinations model selection, to conduct multiple logistic regression that should distinguish between use (1) and available points (0).

I used univariate models to determine whether predictors should be modelled as linear terms or quadratic terms by building models as follows:

```
linmod <- glm(predictor, data = data, family = binomial)
quadmod <- glm(predictor + I(predictor^2), data = data, family = binomial)
```

If `quadmod` was associated with an AIC value less than 2 smaller than that associated with `linmod`, I allowed the predictor in question to be either quadratic or linear in the final all possible combinations approach (dredge function).

The all possible combinations approach led to a top model that included a positive quadratic term (`DecScatOG`). Model performance was good according to ROC AUC, cross validation and pseudo R2. BUT when I plotted the predicted effect of the predictor in question (i.e., marginal effect), I got a distribution that doesn't look very quadratic at all. It looks super linear!

```
plot_model(FinalModel, type = "pred", terms = "DecScatOG", ci.lvl = 0.95)
```

[image]

I removed the term `I(DecScatOG^2)` from the model, retaining only `DecScatOG` (i.e., retaining the predictor as a linear term, but not a quadratic term). Doing so increased BIC by ~ 11. The marginal effects plot still looked like a linear distribution, as follows:

[image]

I'm very confused about how modelling a predictor as a quadratic could lower BIC if the 'quadratic' term really doesn't look like it fits a quadratic distribution...

For context, the variable in question, `DecScatOG` is decay distance to nearest scat. It's a transformed variable so that 0 is at the scat, and 1 is > ~50 m from the scat. Transformation occurred prior to model construction.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither plot looks linear to me, and neither should. They should both look S-shaped because they are logistic functions, and they do, though the range of your predictor is not wide enough for the full S-shape to be apparent. Whether something like a parabola will show up in the plot of the predicted probabilities will depend on what the intercept and coefficients are that describe the linear predictor in the model with the square. But the linear predictor is not the same as the predicted probabilities. Judging the fit of your model by sight is not a good way to assess which terms belong in the model when your model is nonlinear (e.g., logistic). If you look carefully at the axes and predicted probabilities, you will see that the two models make different predictions for each value of the predictor; this is why the quadratic model is superior (i.e., because the predictions are, apparently, better than in the model without the square).